# Editing dconf keys without dconf-editor

Tags: dconf

I have a machine without dconf-tools installed.

It also does not have internet access, and can not be made to have it.

I have to disable auto opening of nautilus windows on device mount. There are instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB. This requires editing some dconf keys.

How can I edit these keys without dconf-tools, and without installing anything else? Are they in the file system somewhere?

Comment: @Doorknob You *had* to spoil my day? I had forgotten about that question :P

Comment: Thanks @Doorknob! Sorry, search Fu is cramped a bit by phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsettings` to change most of these. For example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```

See:

```
man gsettings
```

For other `gsettings` related commands that will probably come in handy. dconf-editor is really quite useful though, it might be worth installing offline if possible.